# No desktop after power outage

Tags: desktop, process-explorer

My company supports two servers overseas and there was a power outage over the weekend. The outage lasted for about 20 minutes so the UPS's couldn't hold the charge. When one of the servers came back up there was no desktop. I can ctl-alt-del, run task manager and I see explorer.exe is running. If I kill explorer.exe and re-run it the desktop will show up. Will I have to do this each time or has anyone run into this situation before? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Answer (score 2):

So after rebooting, the desktop still doesn't show up?

Try doing a scandisk and see if there is some possible file corruption.

Comment: Correct. I rebooted and still no desktop. I will relay that to my higher-ups. thanks

Comment: Seems strange - File corruption most likely possibility. Either in some file or maybe in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes malware hooks into explorer.exe. If it's badly written, it may be causing the shell to crash.